# how to load all products images in views

Tags: views, commerce

I am using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), I have a content type."Product display" and a commerce product entity,"Product", when I create a node I create some product type inside it (it have product entity reference field with multiple value field),some of products not have any image(product entity has a image field),this is all I have. I want to create a list of product display  ( as a product list that each row has one image,title , .... ).

**Problem:** When I try to do this with views, I create a content type views set a relation to product, then when try to load only one image, I add image field and in `Multiple field settings`  I check `Display all values in the same row` and set `display` number to "1" , but Drupal only try to load first product images that exist in node , it's mean if first product image (I drag them in edit but nothing change and its load images from lower product id only),and if there is not any image it is not load anything, that project using `drupal 7.20 and views 3`.

Where is the problem? How can I achieve loading one image from product images and maybe some product reference not have image? Maybe it is because of left join and if it was right join work correctly

Comment: You should not be running Drupal 7.20 (on a live environment) due to SA-CORE-2014-006 https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-006

Comment: @darol100 I know :D ,but it is not my site,it is a site of my new company customers,I will try to upgrade it later(when I have free time) ;)